# How to include JS/CSS files into templates of Slim Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, xampp, slim

I am developing a simple web app with Slim framework. I got stuck with a probably simple problem. I want to include static files (CSS and Javascript) into my template.

My project folder structure is as follows:

```
index.php //<=== where all the routing happens.
/flot
      layout.css
      jquery.js
      ....
/templates
      first_template.php
```

My header of first_template.php contains:

```
<link href="../flot/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../flot/jquery.js"></script>
```

When I call the projects root url

```
http://localhost/xampp/ProjectX/
```

(I'm using XAMPP) the template shows up, but the css and javascript stuff is not working. The Google Chrome console shows:

```
GET http://localhost/xampp/ProjectX/flot/layout.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/xampp/ProjectX/flot/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any suggestions? I spent almonst one hour in googling, but the overall documentation of the Slim framework is still literally slim :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are displaying your Template on the Project root (index.php), so you should remove the `../` from your Stylesheet and JS relative Paths:

```
<link href="flot/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
```