# JS/CSS 404 not found using Slim Framework

Tags: html, dependencies, resources, slim

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600861/how-to-include-js-css-files-into-templates-of-slim-framework) question, but does not solved my case, even if is very similar.

I am using Slim framework.

This is my project structure. The Slim routing happens into the `public` folder.

[image]

The page `templates/index.phtml` needs some JS and CSS, but I get 404 not found.

My `templates/index.phtml` requires:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My WebSite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global.css">
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

And I get (for example for the `index.js`):

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.js was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at blah.blah.blah Port 443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Slim framework but I know you're using a `router` and a `public` folder which leads me to believe that it can't access `index.js` because it's out of scope. Perhaps try moving your `script` folder inside your `public` folder and see if that works! :)

Comment: Solved by putting those folders into `public` and using absolute path e.g. `href="/style/global.css"` instead of `href="style/global.css"`.